# container process label is set to spc_t after setting selinux-enable=true in containerd-config.toml

Tags: kubernetes, selinux, containerd

containerd: file label is container_ro_file_t but container process runs as spc_t. Is process label spc_t correct if selinux enabled for containerd or did i miss some setting with containerd?

K8s version: 1.23.8
Containerd version: 1.6.6

selinux enable by setting [enable_selinux = true] in /etc/containerd/config.toml

// create pod using tomcat official image then check the process and file label
$kubectl exec tomcat -it -- ps -eZ
system_u:system_r:spc_t:s0            1 ?        00:00:26 java
system_u:system_r:spc_t:s0           45 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

$kubectl exec tomcat  -it -- ls -FlaZ
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0  4096 Jun 28 00:54 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0  4096 Jun 28 00:50 ../
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root system_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0  4096 Jun 28 00:54 bin/

#containerd is running as container_runtime_t: 
$ps -eZ | grep containerd 
system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 912 ?   00:00:10 containerd
system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 1327 ?  00:00:00 containerd-shim

//seems run as spc_t is correct
$sesearch -T -t container_var_lib_t | grep spc_t
type_transition container_runtime_t container_ro_file_t : process spc_t;

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after adding version in /etc/containerd/config.toml
`version=2`